# Unable to call Salesforce API using Spring RestTemplate but working in postman

Tags: spring-boot, salesforce, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I am trying to call Salesforce end point but I am unable to call it using spring boot, But with postman it is working

```
        String oauthUrl = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";

        // Create a multi value map to put necessary attributes
        // for the authentication request
        MultiValueMap<String, String> mvMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        mvMap.add("grant_type", "password");
        mvMap.add("client_id", "*****");
        mvMap.add("client_secret",”*****");
        mvMap.add("username", "test");
        mvMap.add("password", "*****");

        

        
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Map<String, String> token = restTemplate.postForObject(oauthUrl, mvMap, Map.class);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Access Token  :: "+token.get("access_token"));
        System.out.println("Instance Url  :: "+token.get("instance_url"));
        System.out.println("Id  :: "+token.get("id"));
        System.out.println("Token_Type  :: "+token.get("token_type"));
        System.out.println("Signature  :: "+token.get("signature"));
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
```

````
2023-10-04T18:03:02.232+05:30[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m26636[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token": Connection timed out: connect] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579) ~[na:na] ```
````

Comment: Maybe you shouldn’t post your secrets…

Comment: Its not original working secrets.